# Is it Haram to take interest in a game?

Tags: riba, money

We know that Riba interest is Haram .
Does this apply to games as well  ?

Example : MONOPOLY

Is it haram to take interest from another player  ? The money is not real world money and has no real monetary value. Is this haram?

What about depositing money in the bank and takING it afterwards  ( with interest ) ?

Example 2 : Video Games

In a certain video game,  it is possible to deposit some money in a bank and take it back with interest  ?

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't .

Comment: For example 1 (like no real money) it is altogether different topic like playing of games etc (that can come under no worldly benefits as well but just game playing) So its different kind of scenario.. But for example 2 and all riba related things mostly, I have posted the answer

Answer (score -1):

Haram is haram, no matter how sugar coated the thing gets. Interest is haram in any form anywhere.

[image]